# Regenerar indices en un pandas dataframe tras eliminar filas

Tags: pandas

Tengo un dataframe en Pandas con 30000 registros.

```
len(data)
```

devuelve 30000. A este df  le elimino ciertas filas y luego,
regenero (ó eso creo) los indices con:

```
data.drop(icond1,inplace=True)
data.reset_index(drop=True)
len(data)
```

devuelve 28070. Entonces entiendo que si hago

```
data.index.values > 28070
```

debería devolver siempre [False,False,...False] y sin embargo, devuelve: [False,False,...,True,True]. ¿Qué hago mal? ¿Acaso no borra los índices
antiguos?

¿Alguna idea de qué estoy haciendo mal? Quiero indices correlativos, no un df que tenga las mismas filas que antes salvo que las que cumplen icond1 sean inaccesibles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un detalle importante que no muestras es cómo haces el `icond1` que te sirve para filtrar los valores.

Supongamos que está correctamente hecho. La fuente más probable de error sería la línea en que reseteas el índice, ya que eso no es una operación "`inplace`", sino que retorna un dataframe nuevo con el índice reconstruido, pero no modifica el dataframe original. Lo arreglas haciendo `data = data.reset_index(...)`, o también añadiendo el parámetro `inplace=True`.

Como demostración de que esto funciona bien, adjunto el siguiente ejemplo, en el que creo un dataframe con una única columna ("data") que contiene números correlativos de 0 a 3000. Después uso `drop()` para eliminar las filas que contengan valores entre 50 (incluido) y 100 (excluido). El dataframe resultante tendrá 2950 elementos. Finalmente reindexo.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(3000)), columns=["data"])
>>> df.drop(df[(df.data >= 50) & (df.data < 100)].index, inplace=True)
>>> df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
>>> len(df)
2950
```

Y se cumple lo que tú correctamente suponías:

```py
>>> any(df.index.values > 2949)
False
```

**Nota:** Ante una pregunta adicional del usuario, aclaro lo siguiente. La función `reset_index()` elimina los valores del índice actual, sustituyéndolos por un entero que comienza en 0 y crece correlativamente. Por defecto crea un nuevo *dataframe* (no altera el original) y lo retorna. También por defecto añade una columna nueva al dataframe resultante, en la que copia los valores que antes tenía el índice, y llama a esta columna `"index"`.

La opción `inplace=True` es para que en lugar de retornar un dataframe nuevo, haga los cambios sobre el propio dataframe, y la opción `drop=True` es para que no cree la columna nueva llamada "index" con los valores del antiguo índice.